# Generating a menu for a tkinter window doesn’t work using a function but works just fine if the steps are executed on a python console

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I’m trying to generate a set of menus for a program from a dictionary using a more complex version of the function `build_menu` below. The function detects what it is supposed to do correctly (detects the structure of submenus and menu entries as desired) but it fails to add them to the window.

Things I have tried:

- running the code step by step in a python console - works as intended
- storing the menu objects in a `global` list so they don’t go out of scope in case they get garbage collected - didn’t work

What am I missing?

```py
import tkinter as tk

def not_implemented():
    pass

def build_menu(structure_dict, menu):
    for entry in structure_dict:
        if isinstance(structure_dict[entry], dict):
            submenu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=False)
            build_menu(structure_dict[entry], submenu)
            menu.add_cascade(label=entry, menu=submenu)
        if callable(structure_dict[entry]):
            menu.add_command(label=entry, command=structure_dict[entry])

# format:
#   "":{} -> menu or submenu
#   "":function -> menu entry
menu_structure = {
   "Help": {
        "Manual...": not_implemented,
        "About...": not_implemented,
    }
}

main_window = tk.Tk()

menubar = tk.Menu(main_window)
menubar = build_menu(menu_structure, menubar)
main_window.config(menu=menubar)

main_window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I am an idiot.
I accidentally assigned `build_menu` to the variable holding the menu bar.

Correct code near the end is this:

```py
menubar = tk.Menu(main_window)
build_menu(menu_structure, menubar)
main_window.config(menu=menubar)

main_window.mainloop()
```